# How to use pv with dd?

Tags: dd, strace, pv

I'm trying to use dd with pv to write an iso to a usb drive. I did:

```
iso="myiso.iso"; dd if="$iso" bs=1M | pv --eta --size $(ls -l "$iso" | awk '{print $5}') --progress --bytes --rate --wait > /dev/sdg
```

Following this guide:
https://gist.github.com/rriemann/1406035

However, what happens is that the iso is "written" very quickly according to the output of pv. I'm guessing it's all put into disk cache or similar. Then pv just hangs. ps shows that pv is still running, but dd isn't. I tried stracing pv, but there is no output, and strace hangs as well! ctrl+c has no effect on strace. In fact, it does not respond to signals 15, 3, 2, or 1. Waited a few minutes for each signal. I was eventually forced to send 9.

According to this:
http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1xvr25/linux_tip_dont_use_kill_9/
The strace binary is badly behaved.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I make pv report more useful data? I know it is probably doing what it is "supposed to", ie, just reporting on bytes that it pipes. But that is not helpful for what I want to know, which is rough estimate for bytes written to usb drive, eta, etc.
2. Why is strace not responding to any signals? My guess is that strace waits for a system call from the process it is watching before handling the next signal, which I would consider a bug. But that is just a guess. strace version 4.5.20.

Comment: That would appear to be a useless use of dd. `pv --eta --progress --bytes --rate --wait "$iso" > /dev/sdg` would be much simpler. Probably has the same problem, though.

Comment: Can pv specify block size though? bs=1M is much faster than the default.

Comment: I think you'll find `pv` just as fast at hurrying up and waiting for the cache to flush... And, actually, yes; that's the `-B` option. I suspect the default will be fine, though.

Comment: @catpants "bs=1M is much faster than the default" <-- The default of `dd`. Without `dd` even being used, you don't have to deal with its bottlenecks.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you could put `dd` on the other end of the stick and try to avoid caches by using its `direct` and `sync` flags.

```
pv "$iso" | dd bs=1M oflag=direct,sync of=/dev/sdg
```

With that you should be caching at most `dd`'s blocksize, in this case `1M`... well plus whatever is in the pipe `|` itself I guess.